# Add ID to dynamically generating image inside <div>

Tags: javascript

I am using some external javascript under div id.
External javascript is generating image which is linked basically ad.

My Code:

```
<div id='xyz'>
  <script src='//example.com/script.js?i=123'>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div id='xyz'>
  <script src='//example.com/script.js?i=123'>
  <a href='....'><img src='....'></a>
</div>
```

Is there any way to add ID to  tag inside div?

Comment: you could use something along the lines of. `document.getElementById('xyz').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].id="SomeId";` or a `querySelector()`

Comment: @mplungjan good catch! I have no idea why i had "S" in the id selector query or added/used `innerHTML` lol. Brain fart.

Comment: Why do you need IDs? You can select the parent `<div>` with `document.currentScript.parentElement`. And you can select all elements around that `<div>` with any other DOM property, or with `querySelector`.

Comment: If the script could be changed there would likely be no reason for the question

Answer (score 0):

Why? That would influence our possible suggestions.

You can in plain JS do this at the end of the document

```
<script>
  document.querySelector("#xyz > a").id="x";
</script>
```